# Subset df by number of tables in word document

Tags: r

I have a folder of word documents I want to extract tables from. The issue is that they have a different number of tables ranging from 4 to 8.

I want to subset the import by the number of tables so that I have df1 contains the documents with only 4 tables, df2 the one with only 5 tables and so on.

I am using the docxtractr package.

Using the code below, I can identity the number of tables in each document. However, I don't know how to subset by table count after.

```
lapply(file_path, function(x) docx_tbl_count(read_docx(x)))
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```r
f <- list.files(path = "/home/sapi/Downloads", pattern = ".docx", full.names = TRUE) |>
  as.data.frame()

colnames(f) <- c("file_name")

f <- f |>
  dplyr::rowwise() |>
  dplyr::mutate(number_of_tables = docxtractr::docx_tbl_count(docxtractr::read_docx(file_name)))
```

Now you have a table with your documents and number of tables per document:

```r
f

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   file_name                    number_of_tables
#>   <chr>                                   <int>
#> 1 /home/sapi/Downloads/2.docx                 2
#> 2 /home/sapi/Downloads/3.docx                 3
#> 3 /home/sapi/Downloads/33.docx                3
```

Now it's time to split it to several data.frames by number of documents:

```r
unique_numbers <- unique(f$number_of_tables)

for(i in seq_along(unique_numbers)) {
  print(i)
  df <- f |>
    subset(number_of_tables == unique_numbers[i])
  assign(paste0("df_", unique_numbers[i]), df)
}
```

And the content of df's:

```r
df_2
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   file_name                   number_of_tables
#>   <chr>                                  <int>
#> 1 /home/sapi/Downloads/2.docx                2
df_3
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   file_name                    number_of_tables
#>   <chr>                                   <int>
#> 1 /home/sapi/Downloads/3.docx                 3
#> 2 /home/sapi/Downloads/33.docx                3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Is there a way to read in the data such that I can perform this operation 

filenames <- list.files(path = folder_path, pattern = "*.docx", full.names = TRUE) 



table2 <- lapply(filenames, function(x) docx_extract_tbl(read_docx(x), 2, header = FALSE))

But I want to run it on a subset of the data such as df_3 or df_4 

I ran your script and I have the document names and count of tables, but it doesn't read in the actual data

Comment: Then use filenames from `df_3` table, like: `filenames <- as.character(df_3$file_name)`. Should work.